# Roles, profile and permission... oh my

Tags: user, roles

I currently dont have a setup on Hierarchy but I think my issue needs to be done on Roles.  Kindly help

Scenario:

***CEO*** - See's everything

***North, East, West & South Directors*** - Can see all the objects and records BUT cannot see other directors activities and notes.  BUT they can see the activities and notes of Sales people below them.

***Sales Associates*** - Can see all objects and records but can only see their own activities and notes.  If they need to share with other sales associates they can approve sharing.

Any thoughts on how can I be successful in this?

Comment: The role hierarchy sounds like it will be pretty straight-forward. It's the organization-wide defaults where you set up these permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- CEO remains at the top as he is suppose to see all the records across
  the company.
- Now, for longer run, its always better to create geography-wise
  roles. So I would suggest creating 4 roles that report to CEO
  (North, East, West & South Directors)
- Now you can create 4 roles for Sales Associate as of now. (North,
  East, West & South Sales Associates reporting to their respective
  Director)
- Going forward as the hierarchy increases, you can add more roles to
  the bottom.

The benefit of this model is - Each director can see data only in his hierarchy. Ex- North Director will not see data of South Sales Associate unless explicitly shared with him.

```
                                       **CEO**

      NorthDirector-------SouthDirector--------EastDirector---------WestDirector
         |                    |                   |                    |
  NorthAssociate-------SouthAssociate--------EastAssociate---------WestAssociate
```

**Sharing Settings**

OrgWideDefaults can be set as per the organization use cases.

While setting OWD on individual objects, always ask - 
"Who is the most restricted User in my Org?" 
"Can he read and edit all data in the org?" if Yes, **public read-write** 
"Can he atleast read all data in the org?" if Yes, **public read-only** else **private**

Comment: He would also need to set Private for the Notes and Activities objects in the organization-wide defaults so everybody can keep them private, unless sharing them manually.

Comment: I ll add OWD related details to the Answer itself.